# jquery: remove content between elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML but I can't modify it manually.

```
<p class="class_1">
    <span class="support">Phonenr:</span> 
    1231231231 <span class="country">country1</span><br>
    312313123 <span class="country">country2</span><br>
    31231312 <span class="country">country3</span><br>
</p>
```

I want to remove this part:

```
<span class="country">country1</span><br>
312313123 <span class="country">country2</span><br>
31231312 <span class="country">country3</span><br>
```

so that the result is:

```
<p class="class_1">
    <span class="support">Phonenr:</span> 
    1231231231
</p>
```

Comment: So you want to keep `1231231231 <span class="country">country1</span><br>` only?

Comment: nope, I just want this part <span class="support">Phonenr:</span> 
    1231231231

Comment: $('.country').remove(); bye

Comment: Ah... the indentation and formatting confused me.

Comment: @SebastianUrielMurawczik That will work only for the nodes, not the text after the `br`

Comment: well $('p.class_1').remove($(this).html()); bye xD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
$('p.class_1').contents(':gt(2)').remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZefYx/6/)**

Just to add a quick explanation as to why this works, `.contents()` returns elements as well as text and comment nodes. So for your example, `.contents()` contains 12 elements:

```
0: text (a newline)
1: span.support
2: text (1231231231 )
3: span.country
4: br
5: text (312313123 )
6: span.country
7: br
8: text (31231312 )
9: span.country
10: br
11: text (a newline)
```

You want to get rid of everything after node two, so `.contents(':gt(2)').remove()` does the job nicely. And as Felix pointed out, since `.contents()` is sensitive to all text, including spaces, if the content changes you'd have to modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Works as long as there is really a line break after the opening `<p>` tag. Just saying that is dependent on the actual structure.

Comment: How'd you know `contents` took an argument?

Comment: @FelixKling - true, however if the actual HTML has no space, he can just change gt(2) to gt(1).

Comment: @Musa - I'm not sure. Experience maybe? I 'm not sure why the docs don't mention it.

Comment: In any case, you just use `.contents().slice(3)` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = $('.class_1 span').get(1); // get the second span
parent = node.parentNode;
var sibling;
while (sibling = node.nextSibling){ // remove the nodes
    parent.removeChild(node);
    node = sibling;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PGKW2/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, depending on how your structure actually is.

`<span class="country">country1</span>` is the second `span` element inside the `p` element.

So, you could remove this and every following node from the element.

```
$('p.class_1').each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).contents();
    var span = $children.filter('span').get(1);
    $children.slice($children.index(span)).remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TWLZ8/)

Comment: just `$('.class1')` would do :)

Comment: @passionateCoder: Or just `p` ;) It doesn't hurt though :)

Comment: I agree that using efficient selectors is important, however, that's not the point of this question, and `tagname.classname` is not something extraordinary.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It just seemed to be such a little thing. You'd have to point this out in so many answers then ;) Besides, neither you nor I know if there are not other elements with that class or other `p` elements at all. So discussing these things are not that overall useful IMO (unless the question is explicitly about that).